# GAM dashboard - Is there a way to prevent ads from showing on a certain page or URL?

Tags: gam, google-ad-manager

Seems simple enough. Instead of blocking certain line items we want to block all ads from showing on a certain URL on our site. Is there way to do this via GAM?

Answer (score 0):

The user interface of Google Ad Manager does not allow you to block ad delivery on specific URL of your site.

If you want to "block" ad delivery on a specific adunit path, you could use the "Special Ad Units" feature (see [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/187805?hl=en#:%7E:text=If%20you%20designate%20an%20ad,the%20inventory%20that%27s%20been%20targeted.&text=Special%20ad%20units%20are%20marked,targeting%20in%20order%20to%20serve.) for details). Then, if you don't select/target this ad unit path on your line items, it won't deliver on it.